# Data doesn't get pushed to Kafka Queue using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-kafka, multiprocessing, kafka-python

I am using Python (2.7) multiprocessing to push data to Kafka queue using kafka-python (1.3.5) KafkaProducer.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import multiprocessing
# other imports


class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, producer):
        self.kafka_producer = producer

    def main(self, conf, nthreads):
        try:
            for i in range(nthreads):
                logger.info("Starting process number = %d " % (i + 1))
                p = Process(target=self.do_some_task, args=(conf, 2))
                p.start()
                processes.append(p)
            for p in processes:
                logger.info("Joining process")
            p.join()
        except Exception, ex:
            logger.error("Exception occurred : %s" % str(ex))

    def do_some_task(conf, retry):
        # some task happening
        self.record(arg1, arg2)

    # pushing to kafka
    def record(self, arg1, arg2)
        message = json.dumps({"a": "arg1", "b": "arg2"})
        self.kafka_producer.send(KAFKA_TOPIC, message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, 
        request_timeout_ms=60000, 
        retries=2)
    obj = TestClass(kafka_producer)

    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description')
        parser.add_argument('-threads', type=int, default=1) # 20 threads
        parser.add_argument('-debug', type=int, default=0)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        me = SingleInstance(args.src)
        TestClass.main(CONF[args.src], args.threads)
```

20 threads are spawned inside which write to kafka. I saw the logs and found out that the process waits for the message to be written in kafka, but eventually it moves on without writing to Kafka. There are no exception raised.

I tried running the same code without threads from python command line and everything worked as expected. What can be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please spawn connections to kafka after forking processes. And please close connection, and reconnect upon encountering connection related errors.